# Problem with LaTeX (TeXstudio, MikTeX): Missing endcsname inserted. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1} Use of ??? doesn't match its definition

Tags: errors, miktex, includegraphics

I have a problem with LaTeX. I am using TeXstudio, MikTeX and the article class, but suddenly my figures have started raising errors. It happened a day after MiKTeX updates.
My code for figures is

```
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1.pdf}
    \caption{\footnotesize Caption }
    \label{fig:fig38}
    \end{figure}
```

I get the errors

```
    Missing endcsname inserted. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
    Use of ??? doesn't match its definition. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
    Missing endcsname inserted. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
    Use of ??? doesn't match its definition. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
    File `Figure1' not found. \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
```

No other errors then those concerning the figures are shown in the log window.

What is wrong? I have recreated the problem in a newly created article file [CODE]:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{underscore}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{csquotes}

    \usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquelist=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

    \usepackage{titlesec}

    \usepackage{algorithmicx}

    \usepackage{algorithm}


    \usepackage{algpseudocode}

    \renewcommand\algorithmicthen{}

    \usepackage{amsfonts}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \graphicspath{{C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Folder\\Subfolder}}

    \titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

    \addbibresource{}% Syntax for version >= 1.2

    \renewcommand\algorithmicthen{}% Remove 'then' text

    \algtext*{EndIf}% Remove 'end if' text

    \renewcommand\algorithmicdo{}

    \algtext*{EndFor}% Remove 'end if' text

    \usepackage{multirow}

    \usepackage[figurename=Fig.,labelsep=endash,labelfont=bf]{caption}

    \usepackage{longtable}

    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{amsthm}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

    \theoremstyle{definition}

    \usepackage{appendix}

    \providecommand{\keywords}[1]
    {
        \small  
        \textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1
    }


    \usepackage{authblk}



    \title{Title}

    \author{Author}

    \affil{\footnotesize{something}}

    \date{\footnotesize \today}

    \begin{document}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
    
            \footnotesize \lipsum
    
        \end{abstract}




        \begin{figure}[htp]
    
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Figure1}
            \caption{\footnotesize Caption }
            \centering
            \label{fig:fig38}
        \end{figure}




    \end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I reinstall MikTeX, given that it happened only after packages' and MikTeX updates? It is probably not a packages clash, because after deleting all the parts of preamble concerning algorithms, the problem persists. It persists even after deleting the import of all other packages, except for the necessary ones and graphicx.

Comment: `\graphicspath{{C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Folder\\Subfolder}}`  is wrong `\\ ` never separates directories in tex. If you must use graphicspath,, use `/` even on windows.

Comment: unrelated but `\keywords{something,foo,bar}` would make the whole document `\small`, did you intend to have a group there?

Comment: Firstly, prof. Carlisle your answer is correct - I have been using an old version of TeXstudio were only this worked (directory with '\\'), but suddenly it stopped. In the new version, after retyping, it works. Sorry, please tell me how to accept your answer - there is no check mark to click on! 

Secondly - actually, the keywords{} command is correct. It provides keywords under the abstract; the rest of the text is unaffected by it. I have used it many times.

Comment: No. `\\ ` in graphicspath has never worked in latex. (I wrote that code:-)

Comment: Well, it worked on my computer! This is not my first LaTeX article.

Comment: Well I wrote that code, and `\\ ` can't work in graphicspath in any standard definition of that command. That is not to say you are not using some package that redefines `\graphicspath` to make `\\ `  work (which wouldn't be that hard) or that the file is not found anyway without needing graphicspath.

Comment: I have this problem with Latek <to be read again> \edef l.123 \begin{document} ! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> \edef l.123 \begin{document} Thanks

Comment: @NEFCRUZ --- Few people will see your question here, and none can answer it without an example code that reproduces the problem. I suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\graphicspath{{C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Folder\\Subfolder}}
```

is wrong `\\`  never separates directories in tex. If you must use graphicspath, use `/` even on windows. (This has never worked, this is not a change, or related to texstudio, which is just the editor)